# What is the purpose of GAE entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

There are some GAE entities created for my app:

- _GAE_MR_MapreduceState
- _GAE_MR_ShardState
- _GAE_MR_TaskPayload
- _AE_Backup_Information
- _AE_Backup_Information_Kind_Type_Info
- _AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation

What is there purpose? Can I delete them?

P.S. Looks like last 3 are related to the backup I've made. Do I need to keep them (the backup itself is stored in the blobstore)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three is service models for MapReduce jobs, the seconds - as you say - is related to the Datastore admin operations (they also performed by MR). The purpose of all this models is to organize the long jobs of MR. The MR library uses the datastore because the tasks are long and memcache can be flashed in the meantime. And yes, if the jobs is finish you can delete it.